# How to tell when a method in an interface is called

Tags: java, methods, interface, overriding

I'm looking to tell when one specific method in an interface is called, given a simple interface:

```
public interface Foo {
  String bar();
  int foobar();
}
```

I want to be able to do something when `bar()` is called in another class, but I want to let other classes implement `Foo` and `@Override` its methods.

Remember that I can't edit the class `Foo`.

Comment: Bar has to be overridden in order to being called. Why not implement it while overriding?

Comment: What do you mean by "you want to be told when bar() is called". Why do you want that? I am asking because there is actually no clean way to do that. Or in other words: it is very likely, that your overall design is broken when you think you need such information (at runtime). So please tell us a bit more ...

Comment: You can do it using aspect oriented programming: http://aspects.jcabi.com/ and specifically something like the `Loggable` annotation: http://aspects.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.22.3/com/jcabi/aspects/Loggable.html

Comment: @Jägermeister Let's say that class `Foo` is part of an application called `Foobar`, and I'm making an application called `Hello` (in which I want to check when `bar()` is called). There is also another application called, say, `Beep`, which implements `Foo`

Comment: You are telling us **what** you want to do. But not: why. That is the whole point. Why do do you think that you have to know when a method is invoked?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just call some code before or after calling bar implementation, i think it is possible by using AOP (aspect oriented programming) and AspectJ.
You can use this topic : http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html

Comment: I can not edit the class `Foo`, and this is not what I need anyway.

Comment: Yes i know but with AspectJ you can mark you interface and method with :@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Loggable)")

Comment: You create new class  MethodLogger.java like this :@Aspect
public class MethodLogger {
  @Around("execution(* FOO.bar(..)) && @annotation(Loggable)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
    //your code...
    return result;
  }
}In order to call the original method, bar(), the advice has to call proceed() of the join point object.

You compile this aspect and make it available in classpath together with our main file Foo.class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not, interfaces are really blind and they offer no way  to check who is implementing their methods..

Comment: There is not; the workaround is most likely that you adapt your design to what makes sense in the Java language.